# Any caveats using SQL Server 2008 CDC off replicated tables?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, change-data-capture

```
Main TRX System ---- Replicated to ---> "Archive"  --- CDC/ETL --> Some NOSQL DB...
```

For performance reasons we never run any ETL off the main transnational system only off the archive.

I enabled CDC on the archive on the replicated tables and it seems to work. So as soon as the archive receives replication data from trx system, CDC finally sees the changes. Just wondering if any issues with this?

Comment: Nothing that I know of, other than that both replication and CDC have their own problems.  Just assess these and have a recovery plan for when something goes wrong.

Comment: What kind of problems do you know of with CDC?

Comment: Not trying to scare you. Everything has problems.  You might appreciate Kendra Little's comments toward the end of: http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/09/transactional-replication-change-tracking-data-capture/

Comment: I think that article is a bit FUDish around CDC. CDC is intended as a way to track deltas of your data so you can implement a proper ETL process NOT use CDC as replication strategy.

Comment: As previously note, trying to discourage you, just pointed you to one point of view. If that is not an issue for you, then just ignore it and go ahead. If I was satisfied with my plans, that is what I would do: keeping moving forward.